# ¿How can i add a url path in html withoout a server, when click on about. Exist a meta name?

Tags: html, github, path, netlify

I need to change url with a click, without a server because i have in githubpages and domain in netlify, i know that maybe using npm and deploy a build but i want something more easy because the site is deploy and we don't want conflicts :( thanks community i try with meta property but cant, i have the hosting in github and just a index.html

Answer (score 0):

I solve it in netlify,going to build and deploy then to Post processing and finally to Asset Optimization, the enable pretty urls, the engine read de href that have a html and clean a pretty url.